# Instagram API - not returning correct number of images on first page

Tags: php, instagram

I need the feed to provide seven images at a time. For some reason, all pages provide seven except the first page which only provides 5.

```
<?php
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}

$maxtagid = (isset($_GET['instatag'])) ? $_GET['instatag'] : false;
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=$accesstoken&count=7";
if($maxtagid){
    $url .= "&max_id=$maxtagid";
}
$result = json_decode(fetchData($url)); 
foreach ($result->data as $post) echo '<div class="insta-square"><a target="_blank" href="'.$post->link.'"><img src="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" /></a></div>';
$nextmax = $result->pagination->next_max_id;
if($nextmax != ''){ ?>
    <div class="insta-square"><a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/gallery?instatag=<?php echo $nextmax; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/next-slide-square.png" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have played around with all kinds of settings, if $maxtagid is set, removing the VERIFYPEER, etc. and nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the use of max_id on first page ??

Comment: It is the same code that each page returns to, from the first to the last. I have adjusted the code, and it still doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `max_id` parameter is causing issue on first page.. try this solution:

```
<?php
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}

$maxtagid = (isset($_GET['instatag'])) ? $_GET['instatag'] : false;
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=$accesstoken&count=7";
if($maxtagid){
     $url .= "&max_id=$maxtagid";
}
$result = json_decode(fetchData($url));
foreach ($result->data as $post) echo '<div class="insta-square"><a target="_blank" href="'.$post->link.'"><img src="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" /></a></div>';
$nextmax = $result->pagination->next_max_id;
if($nextmax != ''){ ?>
    <div class="insta-square"><a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/gallery?instatag=<?php echo $nextmax; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/next-slide-square.png" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Originally that was my thought as well. I have changed the code to this and it still only returns 5 images.